# How to type a function in the React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, function

I'm trying to type a function in the child component that returns an object, but I'm getting the error **Expected 0 arguments, but got 1** in the handler function. Even though I'm typing the function received from props at the top of the code, expecting it to return an object required.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-typescript-24-04-eg91s5?file=/src/components/TaskComponent.tsx

```js
import React, { useState, FC } from "react";


type Tasks = {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  description: string;
  status: string;
  priority: string;
};

type Props = {
  Tasks: Tasks[];
  changeTask: () => {};
};

const TaskComponent: FC<Props> = ({ Tasks, changeTask }) => {

  const task = Tasks.find((task) => String(task.id) === id);
  const handleSaveTask = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    changeTask({
      ...task,
      status,
      priority
    });
  };
  return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSaveTask}>
    ...
  </form>
  )
```

Comment: It looks like `handleTask` requires 0 arguments, but you passed 1. Try changing the `changeTask` type might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Niklas suggested, how about changing the type of `changeTask`?

Example:

```
type Props = {
  tasks: Task[];
  changeTask: (task: Task) => void;
};
```

Also, you are using the name `Tasks` for type and a variable. I would suggest changing either of them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. The Props  -> ChangeTask has been declared as a function  which takes no parameters
   However when called on 2 -> an argument has been passed which does not match the signature